# defining alphabets as numbers not working inside loop

Tags: php

Please check my code below,it returns 0 while I am expecting a result 14.But when I add `A+D` manually it returns 5.Am i doing something wrong inside the loop ?

```
<?php
    define('A',1);
    define('B',2);
    define('C',3);
    define('D',4);
    define('E',5);

    //echo A+D; returns 5

    $name = 'EACE';

    $len = strlen($name);

    for($i = 0; $i<=$len; $i++)
    {
        $val += $name[$i]; 
    }
    echo $val;   //returns 0

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`constant(..)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) to get the value of a constant by name. Try this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($name); $i++) {
    $val += constant($name[$i]);
}
```

Comment: Cause you need to use: strlen($name)-1

Comment: Because you were adding the characters 'E', 'A', 'C', and 'E' together. The characters were each evaluating as '0' in the addition statement.

Comment: +1 Just some minor points: Your semicolon is in the wrong place. It should be `$val += constant($name[$i]);` You also changed `<=` to `<` without explaining that `<=` causes `$i` to go out of range.

Answer (score 1):

```
define('A',1);
define('B',2);
define('C',3);
define('D',4);
define('E',5);

//echo A+D; returns 5

$name = 'EACE';

$len = strlen($name);

$val = null;

for($i = 0; $i<=$len-1; $i++)
{
    $val += constant($name[$i]); 
}
echo $val;
```